# How to show each Iteration Completed in Selection Sort?

Tags: java, sorting, selection

I created a program that does a Selection Sort function of array using the elements our input that is given by the user. I am struggling in creating a loop or method to call or show each iteration that is completed to reach the final output of the sorting. I am all open for suggestions. Thanks!

Here's the code :

```
 private static String arrayToString(int[] a)
    {
     String str="[";
     if(a.length>0)
        {
         str+=a[0];
         for(int i=1; i<a.length; i++)
            str+="|"+a[i];
        }
     return str+"]";
    }
    
    public static void sort(int[] a)
    // Sort the contents of array a in ascending numerical order
    {
     for(int i=0; i<a.length-1; i++)
        {
         int pos = smallestPosFrom(i,a);
         swap(a,i,pos);
        }
    }
    private static int smallestPosFrom(int from,int[] a)
    // Return the index of the smallest element in the section of
    // array 'a' from that indexed 'from' to the end of the array
    {
     int pos=from;
     for(int i=from+1; i<a.length; i++)
        if(a[i]<a[pos])
           pos=i;
     return pos;
    }

    private static void swap(int[] a,int pos1, int pos2)
    // Swap the elements indexed pos1 and pos2 within array a
    {
     int temp;
     temp = a[pos1];
     a[pos1] = a[pos2];
     a[pos2] = temp;
    }
```

And this is how I call them in my main :

```
System.out.println("The array you entered is:");
            System.out.println(arrayToString(Array));
            sort(Array);
            System.out.println("After sorting, the array is:");
            System.out.println(arrayToString(Array));
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understood you well, but if you would like to see how an array was changed after each iteration of sorting you can just add some print to System.out in 'sort' method:

```
public static void sort(int[] a)
// Sort the contents of array a in ascending numerical order
{
    String arrayAfterIteration;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++)
    {
        int pos = smallestPosFrom(i, a);
        swap(a, i, pos);
        arrayAfterIteration = arrayToString(a);
        System.out.println("The array after step N" + i + " is:" + arrayAfterIteration);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey it worked! Thank you so much, uhm does it apply too in all sorting types like insertion and bubble?

Comment: You're welcome :) The approach is the same: after each iteration just get the current state of an sorted array and then print it or do with it everything else you need)